# Should native DLL and JRE address models match?

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

Can 32 bit native DLL be loaded from 64 bit JRE? If not what is the best solution?
Should user install both 32 and 64 bit versions of JRE?

Thank you.

Comment: No. The standard solution is to provide different DLLs for each architecture.

Comment: Duplicate of own post [Can native DLL and JRE address models be different?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190359/can-native-dll-and-jre-address-models-be-different)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the JRE would need to installed and used accordingly. Note, this is not requirement of the JRE but of Windows. From [Programming Guide for 64-bit Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249.aspx):

> ... 32-bit processes cannot load 64-bit DLLs for execution, and 64-bit processes cannot load 32-bit DLLs for execution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a 64-bit JVM but have a 32-bit DLL you need to use, you can run both and have the 64-bit JVM talk to the 32-bit JVM when it needs to the DLL to do something.